# JHipster slow boot up time (liquibase)

Tags: java, macos, spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I am making some demo projects with JHipster and I notice in OSX that the boot up time is quite slow (51 seconds) It takes 20 secs only to start liquibase:

```
2017-12-06 19:18:13.891  WARN 11252 --- [uits-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2017-12-06 19:18:34.044 DEBUG 11252 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger
2017-12-06 19:18:34.055 DEBUG 11252 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 8 ms
2017-12-06 19:18:41.574  INFO 11252 --- [  restartedMain] com.akton.test.DemoApp                   : Started DemoApp in 51.121 seconds (JVM running for 51.852)
2017-12-06 19:18:46.161 DEBUG 11252 --- [uits-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 32269 ms
2017-12-06 19:18:46.161  WARN 11252 --- [uits-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Warning, Liquibase took more than 5 seconds to start up!
```

The machine is a macbook air with 8GB and a SSD drive.

The same project in a windows 7 machine takes only 19 seconds to boot up completely.

I am using the latest version of JHipster (4.10.2) and Java 1.8 in both computers.

Any clues how I can speed up the liquibase startup time?

Comment: Which database? Macbook air is not really a dev machine, have you compared CPU benchmarks between your 2 machines?

Comment: I know macbook air is not the fastest machine, but 20 secs to starts liquibase is too much. Also I started the same project in a vmware with windows 7 in the same macbook air and the liquibase startup takes only 4860 ms, so I think the problem is not the machine but the SO (osx)

Comment: You did not say which database

Comment: sql type and h2 with disk-based persistence in development mode

Comment: Sometimes antivirus impacts badly disk perfs, h2 in mem could help.

Comment: Currently I am using the v4.14.4 of JHipster and the startup time is more than acceptable (4766ms)

I really don't know what happened but now it's fixed.

Thanks and congrats for such amazing product!